# problema con un contador error list index out of range en python

Tags: python, pandas, contador

hola estoy intentando hacer un for para iterar una lista llamada codcadena del tamaño (l) el problema es que me sale el siguiente error y lo eh intentado solucionar con el uso del while pero nada :/ sigue el error, entiendo que es por el tamaño de la lista l y cuando llega al final no encuentra el indice.. pero como lo soluciono?

```
l=len(codcadena)
k=0
while k < l+1:
    for k in range(0, l):
        if (codcadena[k]==codcadena[k+1]):
           k=k+1
        else:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En todo caso sería  simplemente `for k in range(len(codcadena) - 1):`? El último elemento de la lista no puedes compararlo con el "siguiente" `(codcadena[k]==codcadena[k+1])`... si explicas un poco mejor que pretendes conseguir recorriendo el array, dando un ejemplo de entrada y salida esperada podríamos ayudar mejor. Un saludo,

Comment: hola no intento comparar el ultimo intento ver el cambio de numeros en una lista llamada codcadena la cual puede contener[00000000000111111199999999988888888885555] lo que quiero es que e programa entre al else cuando cambie de 0 a 1 o de 1 a 9, es para una lista N ya que lo que hay dentro de codcadena puede variar en tamaño como en forma. gracias de antemano

Comment: es decir si codcadena en la posicion k es igual al vecino entonces pase al k=k+1 si esto no se cumple entra en el else y alli me determina el cambio de numero

Comment: if (codcadena[k]==codcadena[k+1]):
           k=k+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta es en Python el indexado empieza en 0, por lo que el primer ítem tiene como índice 0 y el último `el número de elementos menos uno`, es decir `len(indexable) - 1`.

Por otro lado, si comparas un elemento con el siguiente, el último elemento de la lista no puedes compararlo porque no tiene un "siguiente". Si haces `codcadena[k+1]`, siendo `k` el último índice de la lista vas a tener un `IndexError`, esta es la causa de la excepción que muestras.

Por otro lado usas `k` como variable de control del `while`, también del `for` y además incrementas el valor manualmente con `k = k + 1`.
Si lo que quieres es detectar cuando un item es diferente del que le sigue es todo mucho más simple:

```
codcadena = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5]


for i in range(len(codcadena) - 1):
    if codcadena[i] != codcadena[i + 1]:
        print(f"{codcadena[i]} (Indice {i}) -- {codcadena[i + 1]} (Indice {i + 1})")
```

Observase que generamos los índices desde 0 hasta numero de items - 2. En este caso, que la lista tiene 22 elementos `range` genera desde 0 hasta 20, recordemos que si la lista es de 22 elementos el último índice es 21. No queremos que genere 21 porque queremos comparar el penúltimo ítem (índice 20) con el último (índice 21) y terminar, por lo que la última iteración es:

```
if codcadena[20] != codcadena[20 + 1]:
```

Si hiciéramos `range(len(codcadena))` esta última iteración sería:

```
if codcadena[21] != codcadena[21 + 1]:
```

Lo cual causa tu error, ya que una lista de 22 elementos no tiene índice 22, dado que el primer índice es 0, no 1.

La salida para el ejemplo sería:

> 0 (Indice 3) -- 1 (Indice 4)
>   1 (Indice 6) -- 5 (Indice 7)
>   5 (Indice 8) -- 7 (Indice 9)
>   7 (Indice 11) -- 9 (Indice 12)
>   9 (Indice 15) -- 8 (Indice 16)
>   8 (Indice 18) -- 5 (Indice 19)

En vez del `print`, puedes hacer lo que quisieras hacer en tu `else`.

Comment: Gracias, me has ayudado de mucho!!! exactamente allí estaba mi error!